# subtract item from list based on combobox selection

Tags: c#, list, linq, combobox

I have a list with elements from a LINQ query, and two combobox. I want that the first combobox uses the list as data source but the second combobox to use the same list without the item selected on the first one.
I.E.: I have the list<>: A, B, C
Combobox1 options: A,B,C
Combobox1 selected item: A
Combobox2 options: B,C

Here is the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class AdicionarEquipa_Admin: Form
    {
        private DiagramaEntidadesContainer dbATMT;

        public AdicionarEquipa_Admin()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            dbATMT = new DiagramaEntidadesContainer();

            PreencherListas();

        }

        private void PreencherListas()
        {
            List<Player> jogadores = (from player in dbATMT.PlayerSet
                                      select player).ToList<Player>();

            Player jogadorSelecionado = (Player)cB_addEquipaJogador1.SelectedItem;

            List<Player> jogadores2 = new List<Player>();

            foreach (Player jogador in jogadores)
            {
                if (jogador != jogadorSelecionado)
                {
                    jogadores2.Add(jogador);
                }
            }

            cB_addEquipaJogador1.DataSource = jogadores;
            cB_addEquipaJogador2.DataSource = jogadores2;
        }

        private void cB_addEquipaJogador1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            PreencherListas();

        }

        private void cB_addEquipaJogador2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            PreencherListas();
        }
    }
}
```

This isnt working. DiagramaEntidadesContainer is a ado.net database.

Comment: The ```List<T>.Remove``` function returns a boolean value

Comment: so should I do ' jogadores.Remove(jogadorSelecionado); jogadores2 = jogadores;' ?

Comment: You will have to copy the contents of the first list into a new instance of a list, excluding the selected element (jogadorSelecionado)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- I have made an example of what I think you are trying to do.

.xaml

```
<ComboBox x:Name="cB_addEquipaJogador1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="120,55,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" Loaded="ComboBox_Loaded"
        SelectionChanged="ComboBox_SelectionChanged"/>
 <ComboBox x:Name="cB_addEquipaJogador2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="120,163,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" />
```

.xaml.cs

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace WpfApp1
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        List<Player> jogadores = new List<Player>();

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            jogadores.Add(new Player());
            jogadores.Add(new Player());
        }

        private void ComboBox_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            cB_addEquipaJogador1.ItemsSource = jogadores;
            cB_addEquipaJogador1.SelectedIndex = 0;
        } 

        private void ComboBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            Player jogadorSelecionado = cB_addEquipaJogador1.SelectedItem as Player;

            List<Player> jogadores2 = new List<Player>(jogadores.Count);

            jogadores.ForEach(item =>
            {
                jogadores2.Add(item);
            });

            jogadores2.Remove(jogadorSelecionado);

            cB_addEquipaJogador2.ItemsSource = jogadores2;
            cB_addEquipaJogador2.SelectedIndex = 0;
        }
    }

    public class Player
    {
    }
}
```

**EDIT**: Included version for WinForms as OP is using WinForms

.Designer.cs

```
this.cB_addEquipaJogador1.SelectedIndexChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.cB_addEquipaJogador1_SelectedIndexChanged);
```

cB_addEquipaJogador2 **DOES NOT NEED THE ABOVE**

.cs

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class AdicionarEquipa_Admin : Form
    {
        private DiagramaEntidadesContainer dbATMT;

        public AdicionarEquipa_Admin()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            dbATMT = new DiagramaEntidadesContainer();

            //Needs improvement :/
            cB_addEquipaJogador1.DataSource = (from player in dbATMT.PlayerSet select player).ToList<Player>();
            cB_addEquipaJogador1.SelectedIndex = 0;
        }

        private void PreencherListas()
        {
            //Needs improvement :/
            List<Player> jogadores = (from player in dbATMT.PlayerSet
                                  select player).ToList<Player>();

            Player value = cB_addEquipaJogador1.SelectedItem as Player;

            List<Player> jogadores2  = new List<Player>(jogadores.Count);

            jogadores.ForEach(item =>
            {
                jogadores2.Add(item);
            });

            jogadores2.Remove(value);

            cB_addEquipaJogador2.DataSource = jogadores2;
            cB_addEquipaJogador2.SelectedIndex = 0;
        }

        private void cB_addEquipaJogador1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            PreencherListas();
        }
    }

    public class Player
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: You will need to a if statement to check that remove has been successful. What is the type of cB_addEquipaJogador1?

Comment: comboBox. There are two: cB_addEquipaJogador1 and cB_addEquipaJogador2.

Comment: What is the type of dbATMT?

Comment: @NelsonSilva I have made an example of what I think you are trying to do.

Comment: Im doing ur load code on the InitializeComponent() block and the ComboBox_SelectionChanged on the SelectedIndexChanged and it works  but fails in one point: lets say, I have a,b,c. When I load the form, i have the A selected on the box 1, and only have B and C in the box 2 but If I change the box 1 to B, I still have B and C in the box 2.

Comment: I have tired my version and it seems to work ok :/ I have not include SelectedIndexChanged in my code (correct me if I'm wrong) I'm not sure what that function is?

Comment: EDIT: SelectedIndexChanged  is windows forms I have used WPF, I will look for a simular function @NelsonSilva

Comment: using your code I get my combobox2 empty. I updated my question with all the code from my form.

Comment: @NelsonSilva it worked for me :? but I think you set it up wrong but I have made my answer more clear, sorry :/

Comment: I did it all as you, but my box2 starts empty and has no data on the dropdown :s

Comment: Could you add your designer file please @NelsonSilva

Comment: add this.cB_addEquipaJogador1.SelectedIndexChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.cB_addEquipaJogador1_SelectedIndexChanged); and thank you

Comment: Almost there but still have a problem. If i select 1st the box1 and then the box2, it works like a charm. But then, if I change the 2nd box, it wont update the box1. I mean, not like that, The data initializes correctly, with 3 elements on box1, and 2 on box2 but then he let me do things like have both boxs with the same values...

Comment: Ok wait, seems like its working somehow. I guess this will do it. Thank you very much for your time have a wonderful weekend !

Comment: Great progress!  In your question you only wanted 'I have the list<>: A, B, C
Combobox1 options: A,B,C
Combobox1 selected item: A
Combobox2 options: B,C' @NelsonSilva but I will try and update my answer

Comment: @NelsonSilva Ok no worries and you :D

Comment: it updates the box 2 based on the box 1. Lets say, I have A on box1 and B on box2. If i go on box1 and select also B, it changes the value on box2 to another and erases the value B from it. In a way, it wont let someting like A-A or B-B.

Comment: The way you wanted it has made it that way really as the value of box1 can never be the value of box2 and vice versa :/ @NelsonSilva

Comment: yeah it does the job :D

Comment: @NelsonSilva :D

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:**

Since the list is unique, you can simply remove the item and use it as the data source.

```
jogadores.Remove(jogadorSelecionado);
...
cB_addEquipaJogador2.DataSource = jogadores;
```

---

You will have to create a copy of the list without the selected value. It can be done like this:

```
private void PreencherListas()
{
    List<Player> jogadores = (from player in dbATMT.PlayerSet
                              select player).ToList<Player>();

    Player jogadorSelecionado = (Player)cB_addEquipaJogador1.SelectedItem;

    List<Player> jogadores2 = new List<Player>();

    foreach (var jogador in jogadores)
    {
        if (jogador != jogadorSelecionado)
        {
            jogadores2.Add(jogador);
        }
    }

    cB_addEquipaJogador1.DataSource = jogadores;
    cB_addEquipaJogador2.DataSource = jogadores2;
}
```

Comment: the "edit" you said isnt working. Im using the function on my InitializeComponent(); section and on the combobox's SelectedIndexChanged function and it messes up when I pick on option. Or make them the same, or block in one options and I cant change it...

Comment: What I meant is that you do not need ```cB_addEquipaJogador1.DataSource = jogadores;``` if the combobox already contains the items. If it's not clear, try the other option.

Comment: Are you sure you're calling the ```PreencherListas()``` function when the SelectedIndexChanged event fires?

Comment: No the item, the index one. SelectedIndexChanged.

Comment: All I can tell you know is to insert breakpoints and step through your code to see where the bug is.